# download a movie from the browser

Tags: download

I'm looking for the documentary movie from this link: http://www.snagfilms.com/films/title/christopher_reeve_hope_in_motion/

I'm not living in US and I cant see it. I've tried a tunnel and to record the movie for later use, but the result isn't so good. Also, on youtube, I didn't find the quality I was hopping for (no sound delay, good image quality)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are using Google Chrome, you can go to developer mode pressing CTRL+SHIFT+I and try to use resource tracker. After you'll turn this feature on, you'll need to reload the page and track the resource you need (possible, *.flv file). In a right panel you'll see raw HTTP query, where you can get an address.